# How to Generate an NxN Matrix of a Particular Form

Tags: python, matrix, markov-chains

I'm solving a problem using Markov Chains, to do this I need to produce an NxN transition matrix.

The matrix should contain zeros for the first row, column, and bottom left diagonal, and have fractions of increasing size as the row increases. For an NxN matrix the fraction in the first row is 1/n, for the next row it is 1/n-1 etc. until the n-1th row where the fraction is 1. I've included the 10x10 and 5x5 examples below.

```
p10 = ([0, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10],
         [0, 0, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9],
         [0, 0, 0, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1/2],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],) 


p5 = ([0,1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5],
      [0,0,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4],
      [0,0,0,1/3,1/3,1/3],
      [0,0,0,0,1/2,1/2],
      [0,0,0,0,0,1],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0],)
```

I'm new to working with matrices in Python, so I was wondering what the easiest/most efficient way to produce these matrices for a given dimension specified by the user is (EDIT: I have already imported the numpy module so any solutions utilising that would be appreciated).

Comment: Are you using any external libraries? Marc has suggested numpy, which is a superb tool for mathematics.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis That's a good question thank you. I'm already using numpy for the problem so I'll edit the question to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for matrices I would recommend using numpy. In order to get what you want you could use:

```
import numpy as np

def transition_matrix(n):
    arr = np.zeros((n+1, n+1))
    division = 1. / np.linspace(1, n, n)[::-1] # this changes it from 1 / [1,2,3, ... , n-1, n] to 1 / [n, n-1, n-2, ..., 2 ,1] which is the order we want to add the division values

    for i in range(n):
        arr[i, i+1:] = division[i] # fill the array with the division values at row i starting at column i + 1 until the end
    return arr
```

which produces:

```
[[0.         0.25       0.25       0.25       0.25      ]
 [0.         0.         0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.5        0.5       ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

for n = 4

However for very large matrices this will get slow, but if you stay under 1000x1000 you should be fine.

I tried the answer without a loop and that one is faster for matrices smaller than +/- 80x80 after that the loop is actually faster since it only calculates one division per row I believe. So use the one which suits your problem

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough solution. I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with the syntax in the lines...
division = np.linspace(1, n, n)[::-1] and arr[i, i+1:] = 1./division[i], would you mind expanding?

Comment: I changed it a little bit so the naming of variables is a bit more logical.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with NumPy without loops:

```
import numpy as np

def make_matrix(n):
    m = np.tri(n + 1, k=-1).T
    m[:-1] /= np.arange(n, 0, -1).reshape(-1, 1)
    return m

# Test
with np.printoptions(precision=3): # For nicer printing
    print(make_matrix(5))
    # [[0.    0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2  ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25 ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.333 0.333 0.333]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.5   0.5  ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.   ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   ]]
    print(make_matrix(10))
    # [[0.    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1  ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.143 0.143 0.143 0.143 0.143 0.143 0.143]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.167 0.167 0.167 0.167 0.167 0.167]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2  ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25 ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.333 0.333 0.333]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.5   0.5  ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.   ]
    #  [0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   ]]
```

If you don't want to use NumPy, you can simply make a list of lists like this:

```
def make_matrix(n):
    return [[1 / (n - i) if j > i else 0 for j in range(n + 1)] for i in range(n + 1)]

print(*make_matrix(5), sep='\n')
# [0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
# [0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
# [0, 0, 0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5]
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0]
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```